# systemd/udev/bluez: Removing other bluetooth audio devices when connecting

Tags: linux, bluetooth, udev, bluez

My laptop's bluetooth adapter doesn't seem to be very powerful, and when I have more than one audio device connected at the same time, the audio gets choppy for some reason.

So I would like to write a service that disconnects all other bluetooth audio devices when a new one gets connected. The main issue I run into is that I don't know how to catch the device add event in a way that lets me subsequently identify which device got added, so I can disconnect the rest.

What I've been trying is udev. I already have a udev rule to catch all bluetooth add events, which looks like this:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="bluetooth", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS}="bluetooth-add-event.service"
```

So after some digging I figured that I could write the device info to a temporary file and then reference it in the script started by the service, so I added this for testing:

```
RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo %k_%b_$driver_%E{HID_ID} > /run/btadd-id'"
```

The output was quite unhelpful, though:

```
hci0:256___
```

I don't know any way to actually use this to identify a device known by `bluetoothctl`, which tells me this about the device in question:

```
~$ bluetoothctl info 25:4E:4A:C7:43:C4
Device 25:4E:4A:C7:43:C4 (public)
        Name: JR-CB1
        Alias: JR-CB1
        Class: 0x00240404
        Icon: audio-headset
        Paired: yes
        Bonded: yes
        Trusted: yes
        Blocked: no
        Connected: yes
        LegacyPairing: no
        UUID: Serial Port               (00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Advanced Audio Distribu.. (0000110d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Handsfree                 (0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Vendor specific           (fe010000-1234-5678-abcd-00805f9b34fb)
        Modalias: bluetooth:v05D6p000Ad0240
```

udev on the other hand gives me this:

```
~$ udevadm info --path /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-7/2-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-7/2-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256
M: hci0:256
R: 256
U: bluetooth
T: link
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-7/2-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256
E: SUBSYSTEM=bluetooth
E: DEVTYPE=link
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=34817721040
E: SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS=bluetooth-add-event.service bluetooth.target
E: SYSTEMD_ALIAS=/sys/subsystem/bluetooth/devices/hci0:256
E: SYSTEMD_WANTS=bluetooth.target
E: TAGS=:systemd:
E: CURRENT_TAGS=:systemd:
```

None of these properties correspond.

I don't know what else to try, honestly. Is there perhaps a feasible way to skip udev and handle add events directly through bluez?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the "input" subsystem of udev. The rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="input",KERNEL=="input*",ENV{ID_BUS}=="bluetooth",ACTION=="add",TAG+="systemd",RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo $attr{name} > /run/input-added'",ENV{SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS}+="pipewire-bt-add.service"
```

This triggers any time a input is added on the bluetooth bus. `KERNEL` needs to be specified so it only triggers for `input#` events and not `input#/event#`. The `RUN` command writes the `name` attribute of the added device (e.g. "JR-CB1 _AVRCP") to a file my script can access. Unfortunately `$attr{phys}` cannot be used because instead of the ID of the remote device it's just returns ID of the bluetooth adapter.

The service file is pretty standard:

```
[Unit]
Description=Pipewire BT Device Add Event
Requires=bluetooth.target
After=bluetooth.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/lutra/.local/bin/pw-bt-add.sh
Type=exec
Restart=no

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

The script is very simple:

```
#!/bin/bash

bluetoothctl devices Connected | while read devType devId devName; do
    if pw-cli list-objects | grep "$devName" && ! cat /run/input-added | grep "$devName"; then
        bluetoothctl disconnect "$devId"
    fi
done
```

It loops through connected bluetooth devices and then greps the previously created file for their device names. If the device is known by pipewire but doesn't match the device just added, it gets disconnected.